# JQuery Ajax won't display results in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

This works in IE 8 but not in Chrome 16.0.912.77. Any ideas?

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("test").each(function()
    {
        $("#test").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).find("name").text()+"</td><td>" + $(this).find("phone").text()+"</td></tr>");
        $('#test').trigger('create');
    });
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<table id="test" border="1"></table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: are you missing the closing `);` for your opening `$(document).ready(`?

Comment: No, pretty sure it's all there.

Comment: Just tested in FireFox and it works there. So it has to be a Chrome issue. Is there anything I'm missing for Chrome?

Comment: Try opening the developer console in Chrome and see if you're getting any errors. View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console.

Comment: Sure am: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/test/test.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.       What does that mean??

Comment: Ah, got it. I'll list it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the error "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin", you're running into Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issues.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Essentially, with traditional AJAX you can't access files from another origin (domain). So, site1.com can't use regular AJAX to access content from site2.com. There are ways around this (JSONP being the most common).

You're running into this because, since you're running the script on your local computer, there's no origin listed (hence "Origin null" in the error), and the browser won't let you load the file.

If you want to keep developing locally, you can start Chrome with a flag to disable this local security. Learn more here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Or, you can move the code to a hosted server, and it should work fine there.

Comment: Interesting. This is an issue even though the index.html is in the same directory as the test.xml? And thanks for the info.

Comment: Yep. Directory doesn't matter--it's about the server.

Comment: I have the site up on the server now. Works on everything but IE now. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a Windows Vista+ computer, IE 9 has the same sort of JavaScript console in it--AND a plus, it has it for its older versions (6, 7, and 8, I believe.) So, try the same thing there.